# C++ inherited class vtable corrupted for Raspberry Pi g++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, constructor, race-condition, vtable

I have some code that is to run on Linux (x86_64) and Raspberry Pi.  The code runs ok on Linux, but crashes with a SIGSEGV on RPi.  A derived method appears to not have the vtable populated and I wonder whether it is as a result of a race condition?

Here are the classes that implement the threading:

```
class Runnable {
      public:
        Runnable() {}
        virtual ~Runnable() {}

        // Starts the thread & execute the doWork() method.
        void start() {
            thread = std::thread(&Runnable::doWork, this);
        }


        // Stop the thread if running
        virtual void stop() = 0;

        // Joins the thread, blocks until the thread has finished.
        void join() {
            if (thread.joinable()) { thread.join(); }
        }

      protected:
        std::thread thread; ///< the thread used by this class

        /**
         * @brief The method that does work. This will be called when the thread is started.
         * The implementation should not return until stop() is called (or is finished with work).
         * This is in protected scope as it should not be called except from the start() method.
         */
        virtual void doWork() = 0;    
    };

template <typename VIRTUAL_CLASS_TYPE>
class SomeRunner : public Runnable {
    public:
        SomeRunner() {}
        virtual ~SomeRunner() {
            // do not delete classPtr, as a framework we are using deletes it for us
        }

    virtual void doWork() { 
        // do some work
        classPtr = new VIRTUAL_CLASS_TYPE();

        // notify main thread that we have created classPtr
        // this is done via a condition variable & mutex
        notifyIsReady();

        // do some more work
    }

    virtual void stop() {
       // tell thread to stop work
    }

    VIRTUAL_CLASS_TYPE *getClassPtr() {
        return classPtr;
    }

    protected:
        VIRTUAL_CLASS_TYPE *classPtr = nullptr;
}


// Within InterfaceLibrary.a
class BaseClass {
    public:
        BaseClass() {}
        virtual ~BaseClass() {}

        virtual void someMethod() = 0;
}


//Within ImplementationLibrary.a:
class ImplClass : public BaseClass {
    public:
        ImplClass() : BaseClass() {}
        virtual ~ImplClass() {}

        virtual void someMethod() {
            // do something here
        }
}


// within main application project

class ClassThatCausesDump {
    // ...
    void someMethod(BaseClass *bc) {
        bc->someMethod();
    }
}



bool                                isReady = false;
std::mutex                           mutexIsReady;
std::condition_variable              cvIsReady;

void notifyGlsIsReady() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutexIsReady);
    isReady = true;
    lock();
    cvIsReady.notify_one();
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // ...
    SomeRunner<ImplClass> runner;
    runner.start();

    // main blocks until notified that the ImplClass has been created by runner
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> isReadyLock(mutexIsReady);
    cvIsReady.wait(isReadyLock, [] {return isReady;});


    ClassThatCausesDump dump;
    dump.someMethod(runner.getClassPtr()); // this triggers the core dump on RPi
```

The variable `classPtr`, although passed as a `BaseClass` should call the derived `someMethod()`.  However, when I run using gdb, I see that the program crashes at the call to `someMethod()` within `ClassThatCausesDump`.  It tries to execute an instruction at 0x000000.

The program works on a Linux VM within a powerful multicore OSX machine, but not on RPi.  I cleaned everything then recompiled, then it worked suddenly on RPi.  Then I cleaned again to make sure it wasn't a fluke, then it went back to crashing (it never crashes on Linux).  That makes me think there's perhaps something funny about the way the class is created in a separate thread perhaps?

Any ideas, please?

EDIT:

I don't think this is an issue to do with threading, because a call to the offending virtual function is ok if done within the `doWork()` method.

```
virtual void doWork() { 
    // do some work
    classPtr = new VIRTUAL_CLASS_TYPE();

    VIRTUAL_CLASS_TYPE *ptr = getClassPtr();
    ptr->someMethod(); // this is ok and does not crash
    // This next line is only here for testing because we know that VIRTUAL_CLASS_TYPE is of type ImplClass!
    BaseClass *bc = (BaseClass*)ptr; 
    bc->someMethod(); // this crashes

    // notify main thread that we have created classPtr
    // this is done via a condition variable & mutex
    notifyIsReady();

    // do some more work
}
```

Comment: Please include the code you use to notify the main thread. May be you are experiencing spurious wakeups.

Comment: There's no `SomeRunner::start` member function. Is `SomeRunner` supposed to inherit from `Runnable`?

Comment: Runnable has virtual functions but no virtual destructor (and nothing inherits from it in this example)

Comment: It would be better to post a MCVE (or at least a MCE, even if you can't make the minimal example crash, someone might be able to spot something)

Comment: Besides all comments, in your `BaseClass`, `someMethod` is not declared as `virtual`

Comment: Thanks for looking, I've updated the code now.  This is the MCE for my build on RPi, but doesn't crash on Linux.  If I enter this code in a simple project and build on RPi, it works however.  The compiler on RPi does respect other virtual functions, so is it possible for the votable to become corrupted somehow?

Comment: What if the working function that is invoked by `runner.start()` terminates *before* the call to `runner.getClassPtr()`?

Comment: @Nasha the `doWork()` implementation is a loop that only terminates when the user asks it to, so it doesn't end before `runner.getClassPtr()`.  There is logging when it does terminate, and this is never executed.

Comment: @John, Ok. The next thing is that `std::thread(&Runnable::doWork, this)`. It clearly is a hack in that you're assuming the `this` pointer is always the first argument to a class member function, regardless of the architecture. I'd rather derive the std::thread class to guarantee the arguments make sense together by explicitly calling `instance->*function()` using that very form. Or as an argument to the `std::thread` constructor use a structure that contains both `this` and the member function pointer, for instance.

Comment: Addendum to my last comment: `this` indeed is always the first (hidden) argument to a member function but the compiler might very well use and "stack" the pointer in some other way than how we imagine (due to optimizations, aso), hence making an explicit call instead of relying upon `std::thread()` to "assemble" a proper C++ member function call.

Comment: @Nasha I don't think it is a result of a race condition - see my edit for where the crash can be caused inside the `doWork()` method.  The cast to a `BaseClass*` is effectively what is happening when an `ImplClass*` is passed to a method that takes a `BaseClass*`.

Comment: Then the only way to know is to inspect the running code under gdb, I'm afraid.

Comment: 1) There is no virtual inheritance in your code, only regular (non virtual) inheritance and virtual functions. 2) Your issue is probably related to threads. 3) This is certainly a design issue, not an issue with a particular target architecture.